# Как запретить показ страницы елси пользователь не авторизирован?

Tags: wordpress

Добрый день, скажите как запретить не зарегистрированному пользователю видеть страницу или рубрику, допустим есть рубрика которая выводится
`if(is_user_logged_in()){}`, фигня какя-то получается если я залогинен и нахожусь в разеделе скрытой рубрики а потом выхожу, получается что путь в адресной строке остается и если я не зарегистрирован я могу просто набрать руками [http://сайт/скрытая-рубрика](http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) и спокойно зайду по ссылке. Смысл от того что я скрыл вывод рубрик в меню или еще где-то когда можно просто набрать url и попасть в рубрику.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть много разных вариантов ограничить доступ к контенту.

Можно использовать функцию в [шаблоне](http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2) темы.

Можно шорткодом.

`add_shortcode( 'members_only', 'members_only_shortcode' );
function members_only_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) 
{
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && !empty( $content ) && !is_feed() )
    {
        return $content;
    }
    return 'Для просмотра скрытого содержимого, вы должны авторизоваться.';
}`

В посте вставляем шоркод:

`[members_only]
Текст только для авторизованных.
[/members_only]`

Есть также [куча готовых плагинов](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=restrict%20access) чуть ли не на все случаи жизни :).

Похоже [этот](https://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-user-access) подойдёт.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос в том, что и где выводится. Надо поставить `if(is_user_logged_in()){}` внутри шаблона, который выводит содержимое этой рубрики.

В общем, на сайте не там стоит проверка `is_user_logged_in()`. Функция работает прекрасно, проверено не один раз.