# Как можно использовать javascript на странице index.php в wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Правильно ли будет вставить в тело  файла index.php (своей темы wordpress) код javascript? Правильно ли это будет?
Столкнулся с проблемой, когда скрипт необходимо вставить после определенного блока div в теле body, только тогда он работает. Но подозреваю, что делать это необходимо из function.php, а просто вставлять скрипт в файл index.php нежелательно.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это правильно реализовать.

Comment: Уточните хотя бы какой скрипт. Вы можете где угодно подключить скрипт, но правильно будет подключить его в functions.php. А вот ответить на ваш вопрос, не зная с чем имеешь дело очень тяжело.

Comment: Покажите что за код такой который должен работать только после определенного div блока

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Правильно ли будет вставить в тело файла index.php (своей темы
>   wordpress) код javascript? Правильно ли это будет?

Нет, не правильно. Подключать скрипты нужно с пом функции [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

Подробнее см в документации: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/

Трогать же index.php как правило  вообще не нужно. За вывод отвечают разные [шаблоны темы](http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2).
И если что-то менять в теме, то нужно использовать [механизм дочерних тем](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B)

> Столкнулся с проблемой, когда скрипт необходимо вставить после
>   определенного блока div в теле body,

А для вставки в контент нужно использовать шорткоды. Есть плагины, которые позволяют создавать эти шорткоды.
Или же по [аналогии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625084/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD/625223#625223) написать свой, с учётом сказанного в первой части ответа.